# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, casting, entity-framework-4, telerik

I am working with a Telerik RadGrid that uses an ASPX user control in an Edit Template.  I am attempting to save edited records but seem to be having a problem with the code.  I am kind of new to the Grideview and can't figure out how to accomplish this.

The Telerik example I was using as a learning tool uses a SQL connection to the database and I am using Data Entity so I am forced to do some translation in the code.  In the example Telerik uses this code.

```
    DataRow[] changedRows = this.Employees.Select("EmployeeID = " + editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["EmployeeID"]);
```

This does not work for me so I am trying this code:

> DataRow[] changedRows = results.Where(r => r.SubjectId = (editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["SubjectId"]));

But I am getting this error message:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I try to cast it as int  using the Convert.ToInt16() I get the same error message.  I believe DataRow[] represent a Row of data so why am I getting a cast error and how can get the value of "DataRow[] changedRows"?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably need to cast the column retrieved.  `(int)(editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["SubjectId"])` since it is most likely an object, not an integer.

Comment: I tried that and the erro message changed to "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David L for your comments as I said I am rather new to this and you got me thinking so I did more research and found where SLaks pointed out you use DataRows with DataTables since I was not doing that I solved the problem with this code:

```
GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);
       string subjectid = editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["SubjectId"].ToString();
       int intSubject = Convert.ToInt16(subjectid);
       var results = from r in DbContext.Subjects.ToList()
                     where r.SubjectId == intSubject
                     select r;
       List<Subject> newSubject = results.ToList();
       //string test = newSubject[0].Comments;
        if (newSubject.Count != 1)
        {

            RadGrid1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Unable to locate the Subject for updating."));

            e.Canceled = true;

            return;

        }
```

Thanks again for your response

Perry

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.  One, you are using the `assignment` operator (`=`) instead of the `equality` operator (`==`).

Second, you need to cast your column return to integer before comparing for equalityin your `.Where()` predicate.

```
DataRow[] changedRows = results.Where(r => r.SubjectId == 
    (int)(editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["SubjectId"]));
```